# vite important.meta.env.MODE in Playwright error

Tags: vite, playwright, vitest

I have a config file (constants.ts) in my vite/react repo that determines which API endpoint to use. eg

```
const API_ENV = {
  staging: 'https://api.staging.acme.io',
  prod: 'https://api.prod.acme.io',
  localhost: 'http://localhost:3000',
}

export const apiEndpoints = {
  private: 'v4',
  public: 'x1',
}

let rootUrl = API_ENV.staging

if (import.meta.env.MODE === 'production') {
  rootUrl = API_ENV.prod
}

const server = import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER

const localFlags = ['localhost', 'local', 'l']

if (typeof server === 'string') {
  if (localFlags.includes(server)) {
    rootUrl = API_ENV.localhost
  } else {
    rootUrl = server
  }
}

export const API_CONSTANTS = {
  rootUrl,
  apiEndpoints,
}
```

When I run playwright I get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MODE')

   at src/api/constants.ts:15

  13 |   let rootUrl = API_ENV.staging
  14 |
> 15 |   if (import.meta.env.MODE === 'production') {
     |                       ^
  16 |     rootUrl = API_ENV.prod
  17 |   }
  18 |
```

PLaywright should run my standard dev build which runs successfully. I note all my vitest tests run as well.

Not sure what could be going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, if this code that you provided is placed in some test or as import, during start of tests it will try compile and do static code check. In that time this code part can't be reached or is not yet loaded will throw such error. This is a common case, where playwright does some pre-compilation before tests starts, so similar issues can occurs if the code that you are using is not yet available.